# Retain query in search block input

Tags: 8, search

How can I retain the current user's search in the search block input? Please don't suggest a third party module for this unless strictly necessary. I'm also aware of views exposed filter and that's not what I want.

Currently, I managed to grab the query with this code:

```
if($form_id = 'search_block_form'){
  $keys = \Drupal::request()->query->get('keys');
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['value'] = $keys;
}
```

The issue is that the value doesn't update for new searches, I think it may be cached. So I have a few questions...

How can I update it from the URL and not the cache?

How to grab it only if the current page is `/search/node`?

Is it safe or can it be susceptible to SQL injections if someone directly edit the URL in the browser's address bar and press enter/return?

Comment: You’re referencing the form item incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override the search result page title dynamically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267229/how-can-i-override-the-search-result-page-title-dynamically)

Comment: Have a look at the linked question's answer.

Comment: Solved part of my doubts but the cache still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting `$form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.query_args:keys';`? Don't know if this makes any sense, but worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, I used your answer but instead of the title applied it to the value attribute, it didn't worked. Then I also tried it with the placeholder attribute and doesn't work either. Search block is cached, it applies the first value but doesn't update afterwards. Then I used your answer for the title and it works for the title - I will leave it because it's a nice addition to the search title.

Comment: Like I said, you’re applying it to the wrong form property if you want the input to have a value from the URL. Also you have an error in the `if` statement - it will always evaluate to true.

Comment: @animals Did you try method $form_state->setUserInput() ?

Comment: Thanks @Jonh for the tip. I'm pretty overwhelmed since I'm not a coder and only stuff I know is html and css. I'm at least 48h reading lots lots of posts and can't make this work. [I found this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220316/91552) so I may give it a look later, although I doubt I will find a solution on my own so I will leave it as it is now and move on. I only use Drupal for about 2 weeks and I'm not familiar with a lot of stuff.